# EST/EDT to GMT conversion and date comparison

Tags: php, date, time, gmt

I need to convert a given GMT date and time (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM) into such a string YYYYMMDD representing Eastern coast date. Do you think the code below is OK?

```
$date='2011-11-07 04:30';
$date.='-4 hours';
$date=strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',strtotime($date));
$y=gmdate('Y');  
$date2=date('Y-m-d 02:00',strtotime($y.'-03-01 second sunday'));
$date3=date('Y-m-d 02:00',strtotime($y.'-11-01 first sunday')); 
if($date<=$date2||$date>=$date3) {      
  $date.='-1 hour';
  $date=strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',strtotime($date));
} 
$date=date('Ymd', strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advise against trying to do the calculation yourself. There's too many nuances with our wonderful, ever-changing, time standard. Instead, rely on PHP to perform the calculations by using php.net/date_default_timezone_set to set your timezone to GMT, then `strtotime()` (or the `DateTime` class) to get the unix-timestamp value.

Once you have the unix timestamp, use php.net/date_default_timezone_set again to set the timezone to America/New_York and use `date()`